# (Simulator iPhone 4s is not available.) during validation

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I try to update my pod to **Xcode 8** and **Swift 3** syntax, I did run the following command of my project:

```
pod spec lint BSTableViewReorder.podspec
```

and it produces an error:

```
 -> BSTableViewReorder (1.3)
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun simctl list devices

2016-08-25 11:58:10.561 simctl[34169:531955] CoreSimulator is attempting to unload a stale CoreSimulatorService job.  Detected Xcode.app relocation or CoreSimulatorService version change.  Framework path (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework) and version (209.19) does not match existing job path (/Users/kuna/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService) and version (303.7).
2016-08-25 11:58:10.819 simctl[34169:531955] Failed to locate a valid instance of CoreSimulatorService in the bootstrap.  Adding it now.
2016-08-25 11:58:10.839 simctl[34169:531955] *** Assertion failure in -[SimServiceContext reloadServiceIfMovedOrAbortIfWeAreInvalid], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator-209.19/CoreSimulator/SimServiceContext.m:536
2016-08-25 11:58:10.857 simctl[34169:531955] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The loaded com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService job does not match our expectations: pathOfLoadedJob: /Users/kuna/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService, our frameworkPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff87a934f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff93c8973c objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff87a981ca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8aaa8856 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
    4   CoreSimulator                       0x00000001099953e9 -[SimServiceContext reloadServiceIfMovedOrAbortIfWeAreInvalid] + 1313
    5   CoreSimulator                       0x0000000109995d01 -[SimServiceContext connect] + 41
    6   CoreSimulator                       0x00000001099947a6 -[SimServiceContext initWithDeveloperDir:connectionType:] + 1108
    7   CoreSimulator                       0x0000000109994071 __63+[SimServiceContext sharedServiceContextForDeveloperDir:error:]_block_invoke_2 + 127
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff923fb40b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff923fc9f2 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 74
    10  CoreSimulator                       0x0000000109993ea6 +[SimServiceContext sharedServiceContextForDeveloperDir:error:] + 226
    11  CoreSimulator                       0x00000001099941ee +[SimServiceContext sharedServiceContext] + 51
    12  simctl                              0x0000000109982a71 simctl + 31345
    13  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff95ba65ad start + 1
    14  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
) during validation.
```

**UPDATE:**
After I chnaged the name of my Xcode from `Xcode beta` to `Xcode`, the following error arise:

> Encountered an unknown error (Simulator iPhone 4s is not available.) during validation.

How to fix this?

Comment: I have same issue, I have 9.3 simulator installed... does not work. Did you solve it? :)

Comment: Have the same issue xD im triying to download the Simulator

Answer (score 2):

Simply install **iOS 9.3 Simulator**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

update cocoapods to 1.1.0.beata.2 can fix it.

`sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`

hope can help you